# Writing a query with AS on MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to type a query on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but I find some problems.

In my query, I would to create a temporary column in my request that gives the age of the personn. So I typed this, with [DANAID] being the birthdate of the personn (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.sss) :

```
SELECT TOP 1000
[All my columns]
, YEAR([DANAID])-YEAR(GETDATE()) AS AGE
FROM [table].[PERSONNE]
WHERE AGE <> NULL AND (AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 50)
```

After this, i get an error in MSSQL and I can't execute the request. I get three errors, one on each AGE in the where function.

After doing some research, I discovered the function DATEDIFF so I edited my code like this :

```
SELECT TOP 1000
[All my columns]
, DATEDIFF(year,[DANAID],GETDATE()) AS AGE /* No error */
FROM [table].[PERSONNE]
WHERE AGE <> NULL AND (AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 50) /* Three errors */
```

But I still obviously has the same error message that says "Column name not valid "AGE"" on the two. So after AGE, I tried so name it as [AGE], then by doing some search on stackoverflow, I called it 'AGE' everywhere so it looks like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1000
[All my columns]
, DATEDIFF(year,[DANAID],GETDATE()) AS 'AGE' /* No error */
FROM [table].[PERSONNE]
WHERE 'AGE' <> NULL AND ('AGE' >= 25 AND 'AGE' <= 50) /* No error */
```

But when I execute my request, I don't get any result despite having some people with age between 25 and 50. I firstly replaced <> by !=, then tried to cut 'AGE' <> NULL but it doesn't show anything while replacing the WHERE by an ORDER BY 'AGE' display me everybody with the age at the end and I find people between those ages.

Can someone help me for this request please ?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 1000
[All my columns]
, DATEDIFF(year,[DANAID],GETDATE()) AS [age] /* No error */
FROM [table].[PERSONNE]
) AS T
WHERE NOT [age] IS NULL AND ([age] >= 25 AND [age] <= 50) /* No error */
```

fields in select clause calculates after all parts of query!
Ok and this code

```
 SELECT TOP 1000
    [All my columns]
    , DATEDIFF(year,[DANAID],GETDATE()) AS [age] /* No error */
    FROM [table].[PERSONNE]
 WHERE NOT DATEDIFF(year,[DANAID],GETDATE()) IS NULL AND DATEDIFF(year,[DANAID],GETDATE()) BETWEEN 25 AND 50
```

Comment: AND NULL IT IS special value, compare with it IS NULL, NOT IS NULL

Comment: This isn't entirely correct though. The top 1000 cannot occur in the inner query because you haven't used the where clause yet, and `TOP 1000` MUST have an `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: i refresh my answer (-:

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: reverse your calculation to YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR([DANAID])

There are 2 methods to access the `column alias` AGE in your query. Firstly be "nesting" the original:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
      *
    , AGE
FROM (
            SELECT
                  *
                , YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR([DANAID]) AS AGE
            FROM [table].[PERSONNE]
      ) AS derived
WHERE AGE BETWEEN 25 AND 50
ORDER BY
      "some fields here"
;
```

or, using cross apply

```
SELECT TOP 1000
      *
    , CA.AGE
FROM [table].[PERSONNE]
      CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR([DANAID])
            ) CA (AGE)
WHERE CA.AGE BETWEEN 25 AND 50
ORDER BY
      "some fields here"
;
```

For your where clause you may use `BETWEEN` and if AGE is between 25 and 50 it cannot also be NULL so it isn't necessary to explicitly exclude those.

EDIT: but it would be possible to include `WHERE [PERSONNE].[DANAID] IS NOT NULL` into the query which would exclude any records that would produce a NULL AGE

---

BUT there is a problem not resolved. That is not an accurate method of calculating age. If the month of a date is after the month of getdate() the age is 1 year less than the current result. e.g. if born in December, you do not become 1 year older in January of each year.

**More accurate method of age calculation:**

```
SELECT TOP 1000
      ID
    , CA.*
FROM [PERSONNE]
      CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR([DANAID])

                  , YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(DANAID)
                    - ( CASE
                           WHEN MONTH(DANAID) > MONTH(getdate())
                             OR ( MONTH(DANAID) = MONTH(getdate())
                                AND DAY(DANAID) > DAY(getdate())
                                )
                           THEN 1
                           ELSE 0
                         END )

            ) CA (AGEsimple, AGEaccurate)

WHERE CA.AGEaccurate BETWEEN 25 AND 50
ORDER BY
      ID
;
```

<kbd>[See this SQLfiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65271/9)</kbd>

Comment: +1. There is also a 3rd method, use (duplicate) the calculated expression in `where` clause as well: `WHERE YEAR([DANAID])-YEAR(GETDATE()) BETWEEN 25 AND 50`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    ( SELECT TOP 1000
                [All my columns] ,
                DATEDIFF(year, [DANAID], GETDATE()) AS 'AGE' /* No error */
          FROM      [table].[PERSONNE]
        ) AS t
WHERE   t.AGE IS NOT NULL
       AND ( t.AGE >= 25
          AND t.AGE <= 50
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great. I just had to change t.AGE IS NULL by NOT NULL. Unfortunately I can only select one question as an answer but when I will have 15 reputation points, I will upvote your message. :)